# problems with basic arithmetic in a function (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, arithmetic-expressions

I have defined a really basic function in matlab.  It takes no input and returns an array of 10 floating point numbers.
The problem I have is that when I run the function to return the array I want I get incorrect values, however when I substitute in a value and simply print out the value from within the function I get the correct answer?!
I've posted samples from the code below:

```
% Calculate the terms in our expression
FirstTerm  = sin(Alpha)*(atan(x+d)-atan(x-d));
SecondTerm = cos(Alpha)*0.5*log(((x+d).^2+h.^2)/((x-d).^2+h.^2));

% Combine and return result
Result = 2 * (FirstTerm - SecondTerm)

FirstTermTemp  = sin(Alpha)*(atan(-8+d)-atan(-8-d));
SecondTermTemp = cos(Alpha)*0.5*log(((-8+d).^2+h.^2)/((-8-d).^2+h.^2));
ResultTemp = 2 * (FirstTermTemp - SecondTermTemp)
```

The array I want to calculate for starts at -8 so the results *should* match.  Does anyone have any idea why they wouldn't?
Cheers
Jack

Comment: Can you show what the numbers are and also what you expect them to be? I have a feeling this is a floating point precision misunderstanding

Comment: Yep sure thing, I expect (and I have verified this using mathematica/maple/by hand) to get 0.0979 which is what I get from the run where I use -8 directly but when I run on the array I get 0.0181

Comment: Yeah but what are you using for `alpha`, `d` and `h`? Please provide everything so that the problem can be reproduced

Comment: Alpha = 45 * pi / 180;
d = 0.25;
h = 1.0;

Comment: The array is use is: x=-8.0:2.0:8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left off a `.` before your `/`

```
% //Calculate the terms in our expression
FirstTerm  = sin(Alpha)*(atan(x+d)-atan(x-d));
SecondTerm = cos(Alpha)*0.5*log(((x+d).^2+h.^2)./((x-d).^2+h.^2));
% //Combine and return result
Result = 2 * (FirstTerm - SecondTerm)

Result =

 Columns 1 through 7:

   0.097944   0.133866   0.208270   0.425797   0.692904  -0.140347  -0.124798

 Columns 8 and 9:

  -0.095581  -0.076166
```